# Searching within Hash of Hashes

Tags: perl, hash

Say I have an array and a multidimensional hash. I want to recursively look whether the values in the array exist as keys in the hash. Is there any better way than doing it as follows? (example edited from Perl Maven[Perl Maven](http://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-hashes)).

Note a couple of things more:

1. In the example below, only `FooBar` and `Mathematics` exist in the hash `%grades`;
2. The main question in this post is how to find a more efficient way to search at first level, then second level, etc. etc., given that my real example has about 7 levels;
3. Note that, my idea is to try to tighten the search the most possible. The best would be if all elements in my array could be found, by order, in the hash (i.e. having `@array=("FooBar","Mathematics")` to look into the values at `$myhash{"FooBar"}{"Mathematics"}`; if this fails, look whether "FooBar" or "Mathematics" exist at the second level of the hash, i.e. `$myhash{"otherkeys"}{"Mathematics"}` or `$myhash{"otherkeys"}{"FooBar"}`).

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;
my @subjectsandnames=("FooBar","ThatBar","Mathematics","Biology","Physics");
my %grades;

$grades{"FooBar"}{Mathematics}   = 12;
$grades{"FooBar"}{Literature}    = 99;
$grades{"PetiBar"}{Literature}   = 87;
$grades{"PetiBar"}{Mathematics}  = 13;
$grades{"PetiBar"}{Art}          = 93;
foreach my $name (sort keys %grades) {
    my @possible = grep defined, map { $grades{$_}} @subjectsandnames; #sees matches at first level
    dd @possible;    
    foreach my $subject (sort keys %{$grades{$name}}){
        my @possible2 = grep defined, map { $grades{$name}{$_}} @subjectsandnames; #sees matches at second level
        dd @possible2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing your data and situation in detail, makes it difficult to give complete advice.

However, say that you just wanted to see if the deepest level key was equal to one of your list of subjects.  Then recursing the hash of hashes would be a possible solution like demonstrated below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my @subjectsandnames = qw(FooBar ThatBar Mathematics Biology Physics);

my %grades = (
    FooBar => {
        Mathematics => 12,
        Literature  => 99,
        },
    PetiBar => {
        Literature  => 87,
        Mathematics => 13,
        Art         => 93,
        },
    );

recurse_hash(\%grades);

sub recurse_hash {
    my ($hashref, @keys) = @_;

    for my $key (sort keys %$hashref) {
        my $val = $hashref->{$key};
        if (ref $val) {
            recurse_hash($val, @keys, $key);
        } elsif (grep {$key eq $_} @subjectsandnames) {
            print "@keys $key $val\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
FooBar Mathematics 12
PetiBar Mathematics 13
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I haven't looked into your code in detail (there are a few things that I still don't completely grasp), but from your description I must ask the following: does `recurse_hash` only look at the deepest level of the hash, or does it look also at the upper levels?

Comment: I edited the 3rd point in my question, maybe it is a bit clearer now :)